# Can't assign BoundingVolume for CC3MeshNode

Tags: ios, bounding-box, cocos3d

I want to create a **CC3MeshNode** with **boundingvolume** in **cocos3d**. I have created a **CC3MeshNode** with a pod file. I want to get notification on collision .

```
 -(void) initializeScene 
    {
    [self addContentFromPODFile: @"hello-world.pod" withName:@"pod1"];
    CC3MeshNode *object1 = (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed: @"pod1"]; 
    CC3MeshNod *object2=[[object1 copyWithName:@"pod1"]autorelease];    
    [object1 populateAsSolidBox:CC3BoundingBoxMake(9.5, 5.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];                 object1.location=cc3v(-5.0, 0.0, 0.0);  object2.location=cc3v(5.0, 0.0, 0.0);  
    [self addChild:object2];    
    CCActionInterval *move1=[CC3MoveTo actionWithDuration:3.0 moveTo:cc3v(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)];    CCActionInterval *move2=[CC3MoveTo actionWithDuration:3.0 moveTo:cc3v(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)];    [object1 runAction:move1];    
    [object2 runAction:move2];
    }
        -(void) updateAfterTransform: (CC3NodeUpdatingVisitor*) visitor
         {
                if([object1 doesIntersectNode:object2])       
                NSLog(@"Collision !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
```

I tried to assign **boundingvolume** but didnt work. Actually i am confused in implementing boundingvolume for **cc3MeshNode**

Comment: I get error in   [object1 populateAsSolidBox:CC3BoundingBoxMake(9.5, 5.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];

Answer (score 2):

Your comment above says:

> I get error in `[object1 populateAsSolidBox:CC3BoundingBoxMake(9.5, 5.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];`

Here's why you have the error. From the [CC3Foundation documentation](http://brenwill.com/docs/cocos3d/0.6.4/api/_c_c3_foundation_8h.html#acfc60f78a4b4be63230f8beaae999397) it looks like you are setting the max values in CC3BoundingboxMake to a value lower than the mins (they are all zero), in the call

```
CC3BoundingBoxMake(9.5, 5.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
```

That is, from the link above, the signature of CC3BoundingBoxMake() is

```
CC3BoundingBoxMake ( GLfloat minX,
                     GLfloat minY,
                     GLfloat minZ,
                     GLfloat maxX,
                     GLfloat maxY,
                     GLfloat maxZ 
)
```

where your `minX` is 9.5 and your `maxX` is 0.0, your `minY` is 5.0 and your `maxY` is 0.0, and your `minZ` is 4.0 and your `maxZ` is 0.0.

Comment: @ Yatin Saraiya ,Thanks for Your reply.  I got that code from stack overflow itself. And when i tried your answer got the following  error.>>>> 2013-07-17 17:47:31.015 collision sample[3006:c07] -[CC3PODResourceNode populateAsSolidBox:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c829d02013-07-17 17:47:31.017 collision sample[3006:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CC3PODResourceNode populateAsSolidBox:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c829d0'